# Final Cut Pro X: Is there a way to create a project using an automated script?

Tags: scripting, finalcut

I am working on a desktop video file manager app. The app is designed to manage video clips by renaming and organizing them into appropriate folders. It is being used by people that range from modest to high level of technical skills.

This particular feature will be designed to simplify post-production for people with low to modest technical skills.

The app is written in Python using SQLite3. Your response can be for any scripting language. I can translate the functionality to Python.

Is there any way to write a script that can automatically create a Final Cut Pro X library? The ideal result would be a library with certain clips imported and organized by custom event names. Opening that library would then show all the events created by the script with specific clips associated with each event.

I would like to avoid writing a plugin, but it might be the only solution.

Thank you.